# Why on-screen keyboard disappears and typed comment text is deleted on orientation change in Stack Overflow Android application?

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I've noticed that when using the **Stack Overflow** application on my mobile phone with Android 6.0.1 (Xiaomi Redmi 3s Pro), when I'm commenting on someone's post and change device orientation, text already typed as **comment** as well as on-screen keyboard itself disappears. I don't see any possibility to retrieve typed text - it seems to be confusing when long comment is already written and you don't have a possibility to get its content back.

What is the reason that typed text disappears?

I would like to admit, that when using **Stack Exchange** Android application, problem doesn't exist. As an addition, when changing orientation while **answering** a question instead of **commenting** it, problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Xiaomi? Hmmmmmmm

Comment: Yea, I noticed that too on a couple of occasions. Typing an answer, need to move a bit, screen rotates whilst mobile gets moved around, then resume typing and stuff is gone. I have a samsung s7 edge.

Comment: @Tschallacka When saying "answer" you mean "comment"? When I'm writing an answer everything seems to be ok, only commenting causes problems in my case.

Comment: Yea, I meant like answering someone elses comment. Typing answers is okay.

Comment: Screen rotation on Android is pretty terrible, it actually destroys the whole "window" and re-opens it.

Comment: @immibis It creates a new view, because you might have different buttons on different orientations.

Comment: Normally an android app should adapt to the changed screen orientation by using another layout if necessary but keep the state of UI elements like text fields or checkboxes: "Your application should be able to restart at any time without loss of user data or state", quoted from this [guide for developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Let's face it: the Stack Overflow app has been a colossal failure.

Comment: @cybermonkey I'm not a user for a very long time but I agree that the Stack Overflow Android is not the best one, but aren't there people who care about it and try to make it better anyway? I think it's a good place to let them know about some bugs or annoying behaviors of that app to let them improve it. Especially when maybe it is not that hard to solve it as when rotating while answering (not commenting) they were abke to implement correct behavior).

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal There's supposed to be, but it hasn't been updated since June 2017 and it's extremely unlikely that there is currently a planned update in the works.

Comment: @cybermonkey Oh I didn't know that. Is the reason that only minority of users are using app? Personally, I do most of my actions at SO with mobile phone and app seems to be a better option than using mobile browser for it, but... I admit, it's not easy anyway. Seems that I need to leave it as it is now then, if it's not that important for designers of that app, unfortunately.

Comment: I also use the StackOverflow app pretty frequently. For the most part, it works fine, but it does have its share of annoying quirks. A big pet peev of mine is when the screen orientation changes while typing an answer, posting stops working, as if the click handler for the submit button gets unassigned during the layout change.